# highcharts.js: cannot select some points in dense series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highcharts/highstocks 3.0.7 on a series with around 1000 points.
When I hover the point that I want to select, it gets bigger, but when I click it, another one, very near in x-dimension, is selected and marked. See figure.

[image]

This problem occurs even though I zoom the series with a high zooming factor.

Is there a workaround  ?

Comment: if you can provide us fiddle with working example where the issue is reproducible, it would help us to find the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

The problem does not lie in Highcharts/Highstocks, but rather on the data submitted to Highcharts. It happens because of rounding in CSV files converted from Excel. Different time points in the  original Excel file that I process have exactly the same value in the converted CSV file.

I don't know the internals of Highcharts/Highstocks but, apparently, point selection on curves is based solely on the x-value, hence the problem.

I solved the problem by processing, not the data converted to CSV format, but the original data in Excel   file.